# Why can't `blake2_256` prevent the "first key pair" in a StorageDoubleMap from being compromised when using decl_storage?

Tags: hash, rust, substrate

[`decl_storage!`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support_procedural/macro.decl_storage.html) is a "procedural macro" used for storing data to make it available in subsequent blocks.

It says if the user is able to set the **first key pair** in the `double_map`, then we cannot trust that key pair, and so we must use a cryptographic hasher such as `blake2_256` to prevent "other values of all storage items being compromised".

Then it goes on to say that if the user is able to set the **second key pair** in the `double_map`, then we cannot trust that key pair, and so we must use a cryptographic hasher such as `blake2_256` to prevent "other items in storage with the same first key being compromised".

With regard to the **first key pair**, why does it say that it's just to prevent **"other values of all storage items being compromised"**? Isn't `blake2_256` also used to prevent the first key pair *itself* from being compromised (rather than just "other values")?

Comment: This is the fourth question you are asking in roughly 4 hours. Although we are glad to help here on SO, I think (this is my personal opinion), that you should deal with the topic a little bit more instead of asking a question after another. It seems, that you haven't understand the topic as such (at least to *me*). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I've revisited the question and tailored it to just focus on a single question, as one of the questions applied to multiple storage types

Comment: I've also now removed what was meant to serve as a helpful background context (even for my future self), which is my usual practice, and any "brand"-related words, since some users considered it spam/promotion. Sorry, I didn't realise it would be perceived this way.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the hash of `module1.someValue` is `0x12345678`

hash of `module2.doubleMapValue.firstKey(value1)` is `0x1234`

hash of `module2.doubleMapValue.secondKey(value2)` is `0x5678`

This means `module2.doubleMapValue.fullKey(value1, value2)` and `module1.someValue` have same hash. i.e. the values are stored in the same place.

If a user is able to control both keys of `module2.doubleMapValue` and figure out the value of `value1` and `value2`, then they will be able to override the value of `module1.someValue` and cause security issues.

That's why the hash function of key1 of double map needs to be a cryptographic hasher if the value is controlled by a user. Otherwise a user may be able to craft `value1` such it collides with the storage of all other modules, and hence compromise them.

In case a user does not control key2, double map provides a clear all keys with hash(key1) prefix feature that could be hijacked to cause troubles as well.